# Prevent input from overflow grid parent

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Consider the following snippet:

```css
#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 275px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
input {
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <input />
  <input />
  <input />
  <input />
</div>
```

If you run the snippet, you will find that the inputs overflow the parent div along the x-axis and refuses to fit inside the div (tested in Chromium-based Edge). Basically, when you give the parent with `display: grid` a fixed width, the input children don't seem to fit.

I've tried all the properties I could think of, but none of them seemed to keep the inputs where they belong (I expect a nice 2x2 grid where the children fit evenly into the grid). How can I keep the inputs in the grid?

Comment: By simply adding `width: 100%` to `input`. To top if off, add `* { box-sizing: border-box }` for some weighted space distribution.

Comment: @RenevanderLende ah, it works. I actually tried that but forgot that I had a span directly wrapping the input.

Comment: min-width:0 to input element

Answer (score 0):

You could use a percentage of the overall parents width in your grid template column for the parents css. Being you have two items, you can divide 100% by the amount of items and use that percentage `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 275px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}

input {
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <input />
  <input />
  <input />
  <input />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input` `width` is depends on its `size` if there is no other `width` style on it, and the default of `size` is `20`.
[image: Info from MDN]

[MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)